# The Gluon - Does It Exhibit Wave Properties?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, wave-particle-duality, gluons

Do Gluons have frequencies and wavelengths?  I assume that they do, but have been unable to find anything on point in SE or Wikipedia.  Just beginning to study university-level physics here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do, just as all quantum objects do. They have momenta, and since they are massless, their frequency/wavelength/energy/momentum relations are the same as for photons.

But since you will never detect a free gluon, as they are color-charged and thus [confined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement), this is not a sensible thing to say. Quantum objects *are not waves* (just as they *are not classical particles*), and if you cannot examine a free gluon, you cannot do something like the double-slit with it, and the "wavelength" you might want to associate with it is not really useful.

Comment: I understand that they are quantum objects but I assumed that, like photons, they had frequencies.

Comment: @Tim: You can even assiociate to massive objects like electrons or [buckyballs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckyball) or humans the [de Broglie wavelength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_broglie_wavelength) (and therefore, a frequency). Whether it is *sensible* to do so is questionable from case to case, and I think for gluons, it is not (while for photons, as they occur as free particles, it is).

Answer (score 1):

Yes gluons exhibit particle duality. The gluon has no mass, and therefore travels at the speed of light when created and annihilated in their exchange within the nucleons.

Answer (score 0):

Hadrons contain only [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) gluons, which do not obey the ordinary relationships between energy and wavelength.  High energy collisions are required to create real gluons - which do.

Comment: Well... virtuality is an inexact art, but basically because gluons are confined, they have more "freedom" to be virtual than other particles.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics equation says that the binding energy per quark is 309.76 Mev and the wave length is 4x10^-15 m. So if ever that wave length exist we are not able at this time to detect that small waves.